# Active Directory Interactive authentication in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Web App not working when deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: sql, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-ad-msal

I have a web-app that is used to interact with an azure SQL database. It is working as intended, however when I change from using an SQL user/pass in the connection string to using Active Directory Interactive, I get an error when the web-app should be prompting to log in.

Please note this only occurs when the app is published as an Azure App Service, locally it works as intended.

I'm inexperienced so I'm having a hard time making sense of the error.

Below is my connection string.

```
"Connection1": "Server=xxx.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=xxx; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

And this is the error I receive when the user uses the connection string when loading a new page in development mode.

[image]

I'm honestly pretty overwhelmed with this. It seems like some sort of machine configuration issue and I don't know where to start.

Any advice appreciated! Stack below:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:56718/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt.))
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:56718/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt.)
 ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.39.0.0.MsalClientException: 
    ErrorCode: http_listener_error
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:56718/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt.
 ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.InterceptAuthorizationUriAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.AcquireAuthorizationAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, RequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync(IWebUI webUi, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.GetTokenResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenInteractiveParameters interactiveParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.AcquireTokenInteractiveDeviceFlowAsync(IPublicClientApplication app, String[] scopes, Guid connectionId, String userId, SqlAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<AcquireTokenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Inner Exception: System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass146_1.<GetFedAuthToken>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__271_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at xxx.Pages.xxx.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\xxx\xxx\Pages\xxx\Index.cshtml.cs:line 37
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

```
MSAL.NetCore.4.39.0.0.MsalClientException: 
    ErrorCode: http_listener_error
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: An HttpListenerException occurred while listening on http://localhost:56718/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt.
 ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.InterceptAuthorizationUriAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.AcquireAuthorizationAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, RequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync(IWebUI webUi, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.GetTokenResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenInteractiveParameters interactiveParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.AcquireTokenInteractiveDeviceFlowAsync(IPublicClientApplication app, String[] scopes, Guid connectionId, String userId, SqlAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<AcquireTokenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Inner Exception: System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, String path, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: @DanSoltesz Any luck? I've benched it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting things to work.  In your appsettings for your deployed connection string set it to

```
Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;User Id='your azure object/principal id'
```

make sure the userid is the azure object/principal id and not the azure client id

I made a helper so I don't have to set the userId in the connection string directly but it gets picked up as an environment variable when deployed to azure.  You can get your connection string from configuration, in my case I have a tenant service to get the connection string since my site is multi tenant

```
public static SqlConnection Create(ITenantService tenantService, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var tenantConnectionString = tenantService.GetConnectionString();
    var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(tenantConnectionString);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringBuilder.UserID))
    {
        var clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("AZURE_OBJECT_ID");
        if (clientId != null) connectionStringBuilder.UserID = clientId;
    }

    return new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
}
```

then just use in your startup

```
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(MyUtility.Create(TenantService, Configuration));
```